# Queuing independent AlertDialogs?

Tags: android

Is there a way to queue independent AlertDialogs?

My application receives notifications which generate an AlertDialog. While awaiting the user's response another AlertDialog can be generated if a new notification appears (the new AlertDialog will appear on top of the original AlertDialog). Can I control Z-ordering?

Using`isShowing()` I can determine if a dialog is currently being displayed - is there a way to queue AlertDialogs beside storing them in an ArrayList? I need to maintain a reference to the AlertDialogs as a listener can call to dismiss the AlertDialog.

Would exploring Snackbar be an option?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to queue independent AlertDialogs?

No. You need to deal with this yourself.